# On selecting a checkbox in excel the "Tab(s)" should get enabled/disabled or Appear/disappear

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me with the VBA code

On clicking a checkbox in excel the "Tab(s)" should get enabled/disabled or Appear/disappear

For eg. There is a tab name"Summary" and in Summary sheet1 I have a checkbox. On selecting the checkbox in the sheet1,  the sheet 2 should get enabled/disabled or it should appear or disappear

Your help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Paste this procedure in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you have the CheckBox, for example your *Summary* sheet.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = IIf(CheckBox1.Value, xlSheetHidden, xlSheetVisible)
End Sub
```

There are two references to `CheckBox1`. That's the name of the check box - in the sub's declaration and the code. If it has another name change both references. Change the name of the worksheet you wish to hide. If you have several check boxes on your worksheet place identical procedures in the code sheet, each referring to another check box.

Note that there are two different kinds of hiding a sheet, xlSheetHidden and xlSheetVeryHidden. Both remove the tab from the bar below the Excel window. However, if you use *xlSheetHidden* the hidden worksheet can be shown by selecting `Unhide` from the *Format Cells* menu. If you choose *xlSheetVeryHidden* the sheet will not be listed there and the only way to show it again is by access to the VB Editor or code.